# A New and Full Implementation of Generic Intellisense

Tags: c#, wpf, intellisense

I am interested in writing a generic Intellisense enabled editor for SQL and C# (et al. if possible!). I would like to do this in C# as an overridden or extended WPF richTextBox-type control. I know there are many example projects available and I have implemented a *basic* version of my own; but most of the examples that I have come across (and indeed my own) are just that, *basic*.

A couple of code examples are:

1. [DIY Intellisense By yetanotherchris](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5839/DIY-Intellisense)
2. [CodeTextBox - another RichTextBox control with syntax highlighting and Intellisense By Tamas Honfi](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29154/CodeTextBox-another-RichTextBox-control-with-synta)

I have however, found a great example of an SQL editor with Intellisense [QueryCommander SQL Editor By Mikael Håkansson](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9465/QueryCommander-SQL-Editor) which seems to work well. Microsoft must use a XML library of command keywords, but my question is: How (in detail) do Microsoft implement their Intellisense (as-you-type Intellisense) and how hard would it be for me to create my own of the same standard?

---

*Edit A: A year on and I have managed to develop my own editor control with basic intellisense mainly for my own "enjoyment". I thought I would come back provide a list of freely available .NET projects that helped me with my own development and can be used out-of-the-box and free of charge:*

1. [ICSharpCode (WinForms)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30936/Using-ICSharpCode-TextEditor)
2. [AvalonEdit (WPF)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor)
3. [ScintillaNET (WinForms)](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/)
4. [Query Commander [for example of intellisense implementation] (WinForms)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9465/QueryCommander-SQL-Editor)

---

*Edit B: 15 months after the question was asked I am still looking for new improved editors. This one is nice...*

1. *[RoslynPAD](http://arbel.net/2013/05/11/roslynpad/) is cool!*

---

*Edit C: 2 years+ on from the question, I have found the following projects, both using WPF and backed by AvalonEdit.*

1. [CodeCompletion for AvalonEdit](https://github.com/lukebuehler/NRefactory-Completion-Sample) using NRefactory. This project is really nice and has a full implementation of intellisense using NRefactory.
2. [ScriptCS](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs) ScriptCS makes it easy to write and execute C# with a simple text editor.

Comment: What exactly do you want? The source code of Visual Studio Intellisense? How is VS Intellisense better than yours and what problem do you have with implementing that?

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor yet? AvalonEdit not only has syntax highlighting but also an extendable autocomplete feature.

Comment: I would like to code an editor-like control that can be used in WPF and Win7 Phone apps. I don't neccessary want MS source, just the methodology they use to implement this functionality. It seems that every thing I have come accross doesn't come close to its efficiency. I will take a look at AvlonEdit now. Thank you both for your time.

Comment: Any more updates since last edit? ;-) Thanks.

Comment: If and how did you implement navigate backard/forward?

Comment: @bitman it would depend on which component you used.

Comment: I use AvalonEdit

Comment: Hi @MoonKnight is any control is available just for syntax highlight for SQL in WPF application, actually I want to use in SQL schema search application.  I don't want editor and it just read only control. I can use AvalonEdit but I don't want editor functionally, I just want lightweight my application.

Comment: AvalonEdit is your best bet - it is way lighter weight that you think. Otherwise you will have to roll your own I think.

Comment: @MoonKnight if only it had SQL highlighting... Do you know of any such control that has highlighting for SQL also ?

Comment: You can add support for this very easily. The highlighting is defined in static XML files...

Answer (score 135, accepted):

> How (in detail) do Microsoft implement their as-you-type Intellisense?

I *can* describe it to any level of detail you care to name, but I don't have the time for more than a brief explanation. I'll explain how we do it in Roslyn.

First, we build an immutable model of the token stream using a data structure that can efficiently represent *edits*, since obviously edits are precisely what there are going to be a lot of.

The key insight to making it efficient for persistent reuse is to represent the *character lengths* of the tokens but not their *character positions* in the edit buffer; remember, a token at the end of the file is going to change position on every edit but the length of the token does not change. **You must at all costs minimize the number of total re-lexings if you want to be efficient on extremely large files.**

Once you have an immutable model that can handle inserts and deletions to build up an immutable token stream without re-lexing the entire file every time, you then have to do the *same* thing, but for grammatical analysis. *This is in practice a considerably harder problem*. I recommend that you obtain an undergraduate or graduate degree in computer science with an emphasis on parser theory if you have not already. We obtained the help of people with PhDs who did their theses on parser theory to design this particular bit of the algorithm.

Then, obviously, build a grammatical analyzer that can analyze C#. Remember, it has to analyze *broken* C#, not *correct* C#; IntelliSense has to work while the program is in a non-compiling state. So start by coming up with modifications to the grammar that have good error-recovery characteristics.

OK, so now you've got a parser that can efficiently do grammatical analysis without re-lexing or re-parsing anything but the edited region, most of the time, which means that you can do the work between keystrokes.  I forgot to mention, of course you will need to come up with some mechanism to *not block the UI thread* while doing all of these analyses should the analysis happen to take longer than the time between two keystrokes. The new "async/await" feature of C# 5 should help with that. (I can tell you from personal experience: be careful with the proliferation of tasks and cancellation tokens. If you are careless, it is possible to get into a state where there are tens of thousands of cancelled tasks pending, and that is *not fast*.)

Now that you've got a grammatical analysis you need to build a *semantic analyzer*. Since you are only doing IntelliSense, it does not need to be a particularly sophisticated semantic analyzer. (Our semantic analyzer must do an analysis suitable for generating code from correct programs and correct error analysis from incorrect programs.) But of course, again it has to do good semantic analysis on broken programs, which does increase the complexity considerably.

My advice is to start by building a "top level" semantic analyzer, again using an immutable model that can persist the state of the declared-in-source-code types from edit to edit. The top level analyzer deals with anything that is *not* a statement or expression: type declarations, directives, namespaces, method declarations, constructors, destructors, and so on. The stuff that makes up the "shape" of the program when the compiler generates metadata.

Metadata! I forgot about metadata. You'll need a metadata reader. You need to be able to produce IntelliSense on expressions that refer to types in libraries, obviously. I recommend using the CCI libraries as your metadata reader, and not Reflection. Since you are only doing IntelliSense, obviously you don't need a metadata writer.

Anyway, once you have a top-level semantic analyzer, then you can write a statement-and-expression semantic analyzer that analyzes the types of the expressions in a given statement. Pay particular attention to *name lookup* and *overload resolution* algorithms. Method type inference will be particularly tricky, *especially inside LINQ queries*.

Once you've got all that, an IntelliSense engine should be easy; just work out the type of the expression at the current cursor position and display a dropdown appropriately.

> how hard would it be for me to create my own of the same standard?

Well, we've got a team of, call it ten people, and it'll probably take, call it five years all together to get the whole thing done from start to finish. But we have lots more to do than just the IntelliSense engine.  That's maybe only 40% of the work. Oh, and half those people work on VB, now that I think about it. But those people have on average probably five or ten years experience in doing this sort of work, so they're faster at it than you will be if you've never done this before.

So let's say it should take you about ten to twenty years of full time work, working alone, to build a Roslyn-quality IntelliSense engine for C# that can do acceptably-close-to-correct analysis of large programs in the time between keystrokes.

Longer if you need to do that PhD first, obviously.

Or, you could simply **use Roslyn, since that's what it's for**. That'll take you probably a few hours, but you don't get the fun of doing it yourself. And it is fun!

You can download the preview release here:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27746

Comment: I like the "use Roslyn" solution as it doesn't involve having to apply to a PhD program. Who wants to go be a TA just to write Intellisense?

Comment: Wow. Is your estimate of the work done on C# IntelliSense in VS really 20 man-years? Could you elaborate on what aspects are included/excluded in that estimate? Also, I assume that a lot of the output is also used by the rest of the compiler pipeline?

Comment: @Ani: Well, a number of those people work on VB as well, so maybe its only ten man years if all you care about is C#. But those people *have a collective experience of about fifty or a hundred man years building IntelliSense engines*, so they will be faster than someone who has to learn as they go. As a rough estimate, I'd say about ten to twenty man years to build a Microsoft-quality engine from scratch. Certainly not one man year, and certainly not a hundred. And yes, the code generator and the IntelliSense engine use the same semantic analyzer in Roslyn.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you so much for your time and the detailed response, it is much appreciated. As you are aware, I would like to implement my own, but perhaps a somewhat slimmer version. I had a suspicion that an MS-type implementation would involve a lot of work, but had no idea this aspect of VS2010 was this complex! Having done a Ph.D., the thought of doing another scares me to death... I am not sure I fully understand what it is Roslyn does or how I can use it, I take it is the engine that facilitates/governs Intellisense? Sorry to bother you here. I hope you are having a good weekend.

Comment: @Killercam: Well, the C# language has an *eight hundred page long specification*, and IntelliSense does a complete analysis of code *as you are editing it, between keystrokes*. That's a significant engineering challenge! Roslyn is a library of C# and VB code analysis tools that we are making available specifically so that people like you can use our analysis engines rather than writing your own. We shipped the first preview in October; it can handle syntactic analysis of the whole language but semantic analysis of only a small subset. The dates for the final version are not announced.

Comment: @Killercam: The Roslyn CTP ships with IDE C# and VB editors whose language-specific services are written using only the publically-accessible surface area of Roslyn. Thus you can see the sort of analyses that are possible when using Roslyn as your analysis engine. If you want to use it and have questions, try the Roslyn forum. Or, post a question with tag "roslyn-ctp" here and someone on the team will probably notice it.

Comment: @Killercam Roslyn is a syntactic and semantic analyzer that's currently available as a CTP release. So you don't need to analyze C# yourself. If you write a VS plugin, you can use the same analysis VS itself uses(you will need to wait a bit, VS 2012 isn't based on roslyn yet), so you only need to write the intellisense logic itself, which is relatively simple. You can also use roslyn in standalone .net applications, but I don't know its licensing terms.

Comment: You might also want to look into NRefactory, which MonoDevelop and SharpDevelop use instead of Roslyn. I don't know if it is fast enough to work while the user enters the code. | As a metadata reader, I can recommend Mono.Cecil. Loading assemblies in a reflection-only context on the other hand is very painful. I haven't worked with CCI, so I don't know how well it works.

Comment: @Killercam: Since it's all made up and the points don't matter, I'm unconcerned.

Comment: Ha. The fact that it might concern you didn't cross my mind at all; not with your rep anyway. I just wanted it stated here for the record! I have read this answer many times when putting together my SQL editor [with intellisense]; I would be interested to see what you think of it, it works well, although does not parse the entire SQL language which was well beyond me. Thanks again, all the best.

Answer (score 19):

This is an area where Microsoft typically produces great results - Microsoft developer tools really are awesome. And there is a clear commercial advantage for sales of their developer tools and for sales of Windows to having the best intellisense so it makes sense for Microsoft to devote the kind of resources Eric describes in his wonderfully detailed answer. Still, I think it's worth pointing out a few of things:

1. Your customers may not actually need all the features that Microsoft's implementation provides. The Microsoft solution might be incredibly over-engineered in terms of the features that *you* need to provide to *your* customers/users. Unless you're actually implementing a generic coding environment that is intended to be competitive with Visual Studio, it is likely that there are aspects of your intended use that either simplify the problem, or that allow you to make compromises on the solution that Microsoft feels they cannot make. Microsoft will likely spend resources decreasing response times that are already measured in hundreds of milliseconds. That may not be something you need to do. Microsoft is spending time on providing an API for others to use for code analysis. That's likely not part of your plan. Prioritize your features and decide what "good enough" looks like for you and your customers then estimate the cost of implementing that.
2. In addition to bearing the obvious costs of implementing requirements that you may not actually have, Microsoft also carries some costs that may not be obvious if you haven't worked in a team. There are huge communication costs associated with teams. It's actually incredibly easy to have five smart people take longer to produce a solution than it takes for a single smart person to produce the equivalent solution. There are aspects of Microsoft's hiring practices and organizational structure that make this scenario more likely. If you hire a bunch of smart people with egos and then empower all of them to make decisions, you too can get a 5% better solution for 500% of the cost. That 5% better solution might be profitable for Microsoft, but it could be deadly for a small company.
3. Going from a 1 person solution to a 5 person solution increases the costs, but that's just the intra-team development costs. Microsoft has *separate* teams that are devoted to (roughly) design, development, and testing even for a single feature. The project-related communication between peers across these boundaries has higher friction than within each of the disciplines. This not only increases communication costs between individuals, but it also results in larger team sizes. And more than that - since it's not a single team of 12 individuals, but is instead 3 teams of 5 individuals, there is 3x the upward communication cost. More costs that Microsoft has chosen to carry that may not translate to similar costs for other companies.

My point here is not to describe Microsoft as an inefficient company. My point is that Microsoft makes a ton of decisions about everything from hiring, to team organization, to design and implementation that start from assumptions about profitability and risk that simply do not apply to companies that are not Microsoft.

In terms of the intellisense thing, there are various ways of thinking about the problem. Microsoft is producing a very generic, reusable solution that doesn't just solve intellisense, but also targets code navigation, refactoring, and various other uses for code analysis. You don't need to do things the same way if your sole goal is to make it easy for developers to enter code without having to type much. Targeting that feature doesn't take years of effort and there are all sorts of creative things you can do if you're not just providing an API, but you actually control the UI too.

Comment: Re: "Microsoft will likely spend resources decreasing response times that are already measured in hundreds of milliseconds" -- absolutely. If an analysis is taking more than roughly 30 milliseconds, we start to worry. Re: you can find efficiencies if you solve a smaller problem: absolutely true! But the question specifically was how to do *as good a job as the Microsoft implementation*, not *how to do a job good enough for some other standard*, so that's the question I answered.

Comment: @StefanSteiger You should try using netbeans and eclipse instead of visual studio sometimes.