# how would you built intellisense for c#

Tags: c#, intellisense, code-completion

I'd like to build simple code completion for c# for a simple tool. However this seems to be a bit of a challenge. Suppose all that would suffice are suggestions after dot delimiter and method parameters/overloads. In both cases it's necessary to determine the type of a variable which would require parsing and probably even more work (like checking all available members in the inheritance chain). So generally how should this task be approached? Perhaps there are some useful libraries out there (Roslyn maybe)?

**EDIT**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9556530/579026

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps there are some useful libraries out there (Roslyn maybe)?

ActiproSoftware has an extensible editor control with intellisense support for C# and other languages. You can also define your own language. The editor works on WPF and Silverlight.

(I don't work for them).

http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/controls/wpf/syntaxeditor

Comment: this looks very nice, but unfortunately silverlight/wpf is not an option