# Line by line parsing of the statements written in an editor of an IDE

Tags: compiler-construction

I just wanted to ask that during our typing on the editor of any IDE ,we are always prompted for errors whenever we try to make some syntactical mistakes or any mistakes like reassigning a value to a final variable,or making the local variable static,so actually how does it all happens because all this is the work of compiler and during just writing the program on the editor,how does a particular IDE is able to manage this stuff,is it that during typing only,some interpreter works for whom similar parse tables are made as for the compiler.

Comment: See similar question [Stack Overflow: A New and Full Implementation of Generic Intellisense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556026/a-new-and-full-implementation-of-generic-intellisense) if Visual Studio as the IDE and C# is the language